How to rotate image while it is moving along a given path?
In my app I have an image of a turtle that moves along some path. I want to rotate the turtle every time it 'takes' a turn on it's path so it looks better. This is my CustomPaint class:
class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  ui.Image? image;
  double _width = 0;
  double _height = 0;
  int _ratio = 0;
  final double _progress;

  MyPainter(width, height, ratio, this._progress, [this.image]) {
    _width = width;
    _height = height;
    _ratio = ratio * 10;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    Paint linePaint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 20
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    var path = getPath();
    ui.PathMetrics pathMetrics = path.computeMetrics();
    ui.PathMetric pathMetric = pathMetrics.elementAt(0);
    final pos = pathMetric.getTangentForOffset(pathMetric.length * _progress);
    Path extracted = pathMetric.extractPath(0.0, pathMetric.length * _progress);

    linePaint.strokeWidth = 6;

    canvas.drawPath(extracted, linePaint);
    if (image == null) {
      canvas.drawCircle(pos!.position, linePaint.strokeWidth / 2, linePaint);
    } else {
      Offset location = Offset(pos!.position.dx - image!.width / 2, pos.position.dy);
      canvas.save();
      double cx = pos.position.dx;
      double cy = pos.position.dy + image!.height / 2;
      rotateTurtle(canvas: canvas, cx: cx, cy: cy, angle: 90);
      
      canvas.drawPoints(ui.PointMode.points, [Offset(cx, cy)], linePaint);
      canvas.drawImage(image!, location, linePaint);
      canvas.restore();
      
    }
  }

  void rotateTurtle({required Canvas canvas,
      required double cx,
      required double cy,
      required double angle}){
        canvas.translate(cx, cy);
        canvas.rotate(angle * math.pi / 180);
        canvas.translate(-cx, -cy);
  }

  Path getPath() {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(_width, _height)
      ..lineTo(_width + _ratio, _height)
      ..lineTo(_width + _ratio, _height)
      ..lineTo(_width + _ratio, _height - _ratio)
      ..lineTo(_width - _ratio, _height - _ratio)
      ..lineTo(_width - _ratio, _height + _ratio);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant MyPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate._progress != _progress;
  }
}

The path it takes is something like this:

I've managed to rotate image to any number of degrees at the beginning of an animation.
How can I make turtle rotate 90 degrees to the left every time it reaches a turn?

check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Tangent-class.html

As @pskink has suggested I should use pos.angle here like this:
rotateTurtle(canvas: canvas, cx: cx, cy: cy, angle: pos.angle);  


I did not test it but I think that your turtle is not centered along the path, or maybe it is?

@pskink yeah it was not but I have fixed that
